# How to run complicated query in subprocess.run in python

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

I would like to run the following command using python subprocess.

docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/grep11-cli/config  ibmzcontainers/hpvs-cli-installer:1.2.0.1.s390x crypto list | grep 'cex4queue": []'

If I run using subprocess.call() - it is working. But I am not able to check the return value

s1="docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/grep11-cli/config  ibmzcontainers/hpvs-cli-installer:1.2.0.1.s390x crypto list | grep \'cex4queue\": []\'"
p1 = subprocess.call(s1,shell=True)

Same command with subprocess.run is not working.

I want to check whether that string present or not. How can I check?

Comment: Go and read the `subprocess` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Thanks for recommending the solution. But that solution is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the use of `subprocess.Popem`:

```py
import subprocess as sb

process = sb.Popen("docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/grep11-cli/config ibmzcontainers/hpvs-cli-installer:1.2.0.1.s390x crypto list | grep 'cex4queue\": []'".split(), stdout=sb.PIPE, stderror=sb.PIPE)

output, errors = process.communicate()

print('The output is: {}\n\nThe errors were: {}'.format(output, errors))
```